# Application shows NavigationContainer Error even if i've not used the Component

Tags: react-native

This is probably my first React Native Application and I don't know why am I getting the error, `Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?` even if I haven't used the component `NavigationContainer` anywhere in my project.

project\components\Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Header</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

project\App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Header from "./components/Header";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      {/* <StatusBar style="auto" /> */}
      <Header />
    </View>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "jobsearch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "expo": "~48.0.10",
    "expo-router": "^1.4.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I'm getting the error after using the `Header` component in `App.js`

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` package ?

Comment: @devpolo not using

Comment: I just checked, its not installed

Comment: Can you share your package.json. It would help us understand

Comment: @devpolo You can check now

Comment: What is inside your main `index.js`?

Comment: Btw, since you are using `expo-router`, you are using `react-navigation` (it’s build on top of it)

Comment: @devpolo its just the three lines in index.js => `import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "./App";
registerRootComponent(App);`

Comment: Can you share your repo? Or a minimal reproduction exemple? It's very hard to help with so little infos.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JjJX.png This is it I guess